# solc.exe - Application Error The application was unable to start correctly

Tags: solidity

Solidity compiler is not working on Win 7 Enterprise (64-bit) SP1.

It was downloaded from https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases
Version 0.4.19 (solidity-windows.zip)

solc --version

Error : solc.exe - Application Error
The application was unable to start correctly (0x...). Click OK to close the application.

Answer (score 1):

Seems answer is located here : [Install Solc Compiler on Windows 8](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11081/install-solc-compiler-on-windows-8)

So either MS Visual Studio needs to be installed (suggested 2015) or JS script needs to be written (using Node.js solc module)

The remaining concern is that MS Visual Studio is too huge for installation for resolving mentioned issue. And described solution with JS script returns errors for the contracts which have import statements.

Comment: Is anyone aware what exact software component(s) from MS Visual Studio are needed?